# Trigger graphical password prompt from a cron job

Tags: linux, cron, gnupg

I have a few script to automate linux system backups with Borg. But those script need me to input a password through pinentry (gpg password prompt), in order to unlock my SSH key or the backup encryption key.

The problem is cron run in the background in another environment and it does not trigger any gpg password prompt and my scripts timeouts.

How can I run a cron job, aware of the X environment, which will trigger a password prompt ?

Comment: Don't, it's the wrong way to do this. What if you are logged out? It will fail. If you really want to go down that broken path, then search on `x application through crontab` and you'll see many people wanting to do the same.